# Virtualization enabling in bios

Tags: bios, virtualization, acer-aspire

Can virtualization be enabled on an acer aspire p3-171? I have tried entering bios but I can't seem to find a way to do so. I'm trying to run other os on VMware. My os is windows 8.1, cpu-intel.

Comment: Which Intel cpu?

Comment: i5-3339Y, 1.50GHz

Comment: That processor supports virtualization, but since I cannot enter your bios myself its hard to help you. Some pc manufacturers do not allow enabling of VT-x for some reason.

Comment: Some Acers don't allow HW virtualization to be enabled.  Have you looked under all the BIOS sections?  System configuration and Security sections also?

Comment: Yes... probably this is the case:/